# render report viewer as pdf issue

Tags: pdf, rdlc, reportviewer

I have application which generate reports (rdlc, pdf).
I am passing a string parameter to the report contains domain name (http://www.blablabla).
On server, when rendering report as rdlc , I get the domain name correctly
but when rendering it as pdf, I get the IP address instead of the domain name.

Does anyone have an idea why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Rendering reports will resolve the IP address to the hostname at run time.  In the report viewer the source and destination hostnames will display as resolved names.  However, this DNS resolution is not supported for PDF reports or exports to CSV.

The DNS lookup is not included in the management server request when exporting the report because DNS has the potential for a large latency and may timeout.